# Quotation marks left of line in `poemscol`?

Tags: memoir, verse, poetry, poemscol

I have been dabbling in using `poemscol` to typeset a poetry collection, having previously done most of my poetry in `memoir` class documents. `poemscol` is appealing mostly for its poetry sub-sectioning support.

`memoir` has `\vleftofline` which will, for example, place double quotes left of the verse block, so that the words themselves line up with the left edge of the verse block.

Does `poemscol` support anything like `\vleftofline`, or is there some workaround to get this behavior? (I tried ``` \noindent\llap{``} ``` but no luck.)